# jquery cloning select box without selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to clone select box from previous one ( ie, add select box 'n' number of time from the previous one )
But when I added each time, all the previously selected options should **not** be available in the cloned select box list.

```
$('.field_select_box_list').each(function(){
        $(this).find('option:selected').remove();
});
```

This code removes the parent select boxes selected option too.. but I want remain them to have the selected option.

any help.

Comment: show us how are you making clone of select box

Comment: Add some HTML please!!

Comment: How you are cloning select box? Kindly share that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your clone code can just do something like

```
$('el').clone().find('option:selected').remove().end()
```

The `.end()` causes the selector to return to being `$('el')` rather than the filtered `option:selected` selector, so you can continue running things like `.appendTo()` etc without needing to break the chain.

Comment: Thanks this works... I understand, my question was some what incorrect. actually, I want to keep all the cloned select boxes not have the options which are selected in other select boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use one **select_box original**, hidden it. Then you can remove with  **select_box second** not hidden or add more element from **select_box original**.